# how to merge some csv files into one file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have some csv files that they have different columns , I should merge this files into one file, here is my code:

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd
path = ""
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, sep=',') for f in all_files)
df_merged   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True, axis=1)
df_merged.to_csv( "merged.csv")
```

This code indicates the columns by numbers not their names! What should I do for saving columns names in merged file too?

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a direct implementation of one of the [Pandas examples for concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).  Copying the relevant example from their documentation:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2]],
                   columns=['letter', 'number'])
>>> df1
  letter  number
0      a       1
1      b       2
>>> df3 = pd.DataFrame([['c', 3, 'cat'], ['d', 4, 'dog']],
                   columns=['letter', 'number', 'animal'])
>>> df3
  letter  number animal
0      c       3    cat
1      d       4    dog
>>> pd.concat([df1, df3], sort=False)
  letter  number animal
0      a       1    NaN
1      b       2    NaN
0      c       3    cat
1      d       4    dog
```

I usually like to call `df.reset_index()` on the resulting Dataframe `df` as well, since having duplicate values in the index can cause unexpected behavior. If you're about to do a join on one of the columns, though, it won't matter....  although you've already got `ignore_index=True` in your sample code, so you should be fine.

Comment: you might want to add a suffix for the concat columns in the case the column names are the same between one dataframe and another